Sorting Entry Titles Alphabetically - Twig Children orderBy
I am working with a bit of Twig code for sidebar navigation which displays entry titles in the order in which they were entered.  I am trying to add an alpha sort to the titles like below, but the entry titles are not being alphabetized.
Thanks for any leads.
{% if entry is defined %}
{% if entry.level > 1 %}
{% set sidebarNav = entry.parent.getDescendants(1) %}
{% else %}
{% set sidebarNav = [entry] %}
{% endif %}

{% set nodeCount = sidebarNav | length %}
{% set childrenCount = entry.children | length %}
{% if (nodeCount > 1 or childrenCount > 0) %}
<div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      {% for node in sidebarNav %}
      {% if node.id == entry.id %}
      <li class="active">
      {% else %}
        <li>
      {% endif %}
          <a class="" href="{{node.url}}">{{node.title}}</a>
          {% if node.id == entry.id %}
          {% set children = node.children %}

          {% if children | length %}
          {# order by title #}
          {% set children = children.orderBy('title asc').all() %}
            <ul>
              {% for child in children %}
              <li><a href="{{child.url}}"> {{child.title}}</a></li>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
        </li>
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}

